# Get interpolated data from imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I use matpotlib's `imshow()` to interpolate and plot some data. Here is a 2D array.

```
im = ax.imshow(data2D,interpolation='sinc')
```

I would like to get the `'sinc'` interpolated data after `imshow`. I haven't been able to find any method to do so. Any idea?
Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: The data is the image itself. I don't think it's available outside the rendering context. But maybe you would rather apply some filter to the data before plotting it?

Comment: I know but I couldn't find an equivalent method to get the 'sinc' 2D interpolation.

Comment: Does this work? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sinc.html

Answer (score 0):

The [matplotlib C++ resampling code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/src/_image_wrapper.cpp) is interfaced in the [matplotlib.image.resample](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/2c3f14ed2860641a03b9c6069f43c84feb2b2722/lib/matplotlib/image.py#L161) function, which you can import and call on your own.

Comment: Please give an example of using this method to interpolate an array. Currently it is unclear how the function should be utilized.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to Yannick Copin's answer which reads

> The matplotlib C++ resampling code is interfaced in the matplotlib.image.resample function, which you can import and call on your own.

Here is a visual demo of interpolation using the private function `matplotlib.image._resample`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.image import _resample
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

np.random.seed(19680801)

grid = np.random.rand(4, 4)
scale_factor = 10
out_dimensions = (grid.shape[0]*scale_factor, grid.shape[1]*scale_factor)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3)

transform = Affine2D().scale(scale_factor, scale_factor)
# Have to get an image to be able to resample
# Resample takes an _ImageBase or subclass, which require an Axes
img = axs[0].imshow(grid, interpolation='spline36', cmap='viridis')
interpolated = _resample(img, grid, out_dimensions, transform=transform)

axs[0].imshow(grid, cmap='viridis')
axs[1].imshow(grid, interpolation='spline36', cmap='viridis')
axs[2].imshow(interpolated, cmap='viridis')
```

[image: original data, imshow interpolation, interpolation and then plotting]