# How does matplotlib.pyplot.imshow perform interpolation?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, interpolation

I have a set of binned 2D data that I'm trying to interpolate into a smooth map, such that for an arbitrary (x, y) point I can get a value z that resembles what the original set shows. The result produced by `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` with `interpolation='gaussian'` looks great visually, but I would like to extract this result as a function that I can subsequently use.

I tried using `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`, which I thought is what `imshow` is using under the hood, but the result doesn't even come close.

Comment: Please share an example.

Comment: I did not think that an example would be relevant for my question, but I have also just found the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52419509/get-interpolated-data-from-imshow).

Comment: Then you can mark this question as a duplicate.